# Javascript redirect/logout after inactivity (with modal popup)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The following JS does not redirect or logout automatically, it only redirects to the url when clicking 'OK' on the modal.

```js
           // reset main timer i,e idle time to 0 on mouse move, keypress or reload
    window.onload = reset_main_timer;
    document.onmousemove = reset_main_timer;
    document.onkeypress = reset_main_timer;
    document.onscroll = reset_main_timer;
    
    // create main_timer and sub_timer variable with 0 value, we will assign them setInterval object
    var main_timer = 0;
    var sub_timer = 0;

    // this will ensure that timer will start only when user is loged in
    var user_loged_in = $("#user_loged_in").val()

   // within dilog_set_interval function we have created object of setInterval and assigned it to main_timer.
   // within this we have again created an object of setInterval and assigned it to sub_timer. for the main_timer
   // value is set to 15000000 i,e 25 minute.note that if subtimer repeat itself after 5 minute we set user_activity
   // flag to inactive
    function dialog_set_interval(){
        main_timer = setInterval(function(){
            if(user_loged_in == "true"){
                $("#inactivity_warning").modal("show");
                sub_timer = setInterval(function(){
                    $("#user_activity").val("inactive")
                },3000);
            }
        },10000);
    }
   // maintimer is set to 0 by calling the clearInterval function. note that clearInterval function takes
   // setInterval object as argument, which it then set to 0
    function reset_main_timer(){
        clearInterval(main_timer);
        dialog_set_interval();
    }

    // logout user if user_activity flag set to inactive, when he click ok on popup. whenuser click O.K
    // on the warning the subtimer is reset to 0
    $(".inactivity_ok").click(function(){
        clearInterval(sub_timer);
        if($("#user_activity").val() == "inactive"){
            window.location = window.location // if your application not manage session expire 
                                              //automatically. clear cookies and session her
        }
    });
```

```html
    <div id="inactivity_warning" class="modal hide fade" data-backdrop="static" style="top:30%">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close inactivity_ok" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div id="custom_alert_message" class="span12">
       You will be logged out in due to inactivity very shortly.
     </div>
   </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn inactivity_ok" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">O.K</a>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
    
  <input id="user_activity" name="user_activity" type="hidden" value="active" />
<input id="user_loged_in" name="user_loged_in" type="hidden" value="true" />
```

I would like the modal to appear as a warning message to the user.. letting them know that they will be logged out shorlty... they can click to remain on the page or ignore and it will automatically redirect to the logout page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit*

Now you have everything together except the css... Do not start making webapp by the design, nobody prefer a pretty non-working app.

I've used jQuery since you seems to use it yourself.

`userIsLogguedIn` is not implemented since I have no clue about your way to authenticate user.

`logout` must also be defined correctly.

There is no `Ok keep me connected` since every mouse event will set the current activity and hide the modal.

```js
$( document ).ready( initApp);

function initApp(){
    console.debug('initApp');
    const activityModal = $('#modal');
    activityModal.hide();
    const activityMaxDelayWarning = 5 * 1000;
    const activityMaxDelay = 35 * 1000;
    const activityCheckInterval = 5 * 1000; 

    activityRegister();
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', activityRegister);
    setInterval( activityCheck, activityCheckInterval);

    function activityRegister() {
        popupHide();
        activityLast = Date.now();
        console.debug('Activity set to', activityLast);
    }

    function userIsLogguedIn() {
        //DO it
        return true;
    }
    function activityCheck() {
        const delay = Date.now() - activityLast;
        console.debug("Activity delay is", delay);

        if ( !userIsLogguedIn() ) {
            console.debug("     user is not logged in");
            return;
        }
        if ( delay > activityMaxDelay ) {
            console.debug("     will logout");
            logout();
        } else if ( delay > activityMaxDelayWarning ) {
            console.debug("     will show warning");
            popupShow();
        }
    }

    function popupShow(){
        activityModal.show();
    }

    function popupHide(){
        activityModal.hide();
    }

    function logout() {
        window.location.href='https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65007832/javascript-redirect-logout-after-inactivity-with-modal-popup/65008157';
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="modal">
            <p>You will be logged out in due to inactivity very shortly.</p>
        </div>
        <div>After some time, a warning message will appears ahead</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @farvilain I tried to use your code and cannot seem to get it to work

Comment: updated... but the idea was to give you an example of how to do it, not the exact code to do it...

Comment: thank you for your replies, so just to confirm will your JS replace mine, or should i try to combine both of them together, because its still not working for me sorry, no pop ups and no log outs / redirects

Comment: ah okay sorry, I understand I just dont have the ability to put it together, its like being able to speak English but no being able to write it correctly

Comment: It is definetely working only just not everything working together - https://prnt.sc/vpypjr

Comment: I suggest you start coding functionality before design. There is not point having a great design that doesn't do anything. On the last edit, I put everything you need, now you can make it beautifull.

Comment: I am using Laravel 5 as my authentication, I will try your code now thank you I really apreciate it

Comment: Okay so it redirects when is senses no movement from the user, however it does not seem to show any modal, or even an alert box or something, nothing appears

Comment: Open the developper console in your browser, then wait for a delay > 10000 and the warning message will show up. Change `activityMaxDelay=90000` to have the time to see it

Comment: OKay I did what you said and I can see the warning in the console appearing and then at 90000 it redirects, but im confused, this is happening all behin the scenes in console but Im trying to get it to appear normally for the user please, sorry for taking up so much of your time - https://prnt.sc/vpzfyk

Comment: I put a snippet, run it, do not touch mouse, read the text and watch closely... just READ what appears please.

Comment: Thank you that is much easier to understand.

Comment: With adding more listeners is it possible to do it this way:  
`document.addEventListener('mousemove', 'scroll', activityRegister);`  ??

Comment: Just add the line `document.addEventListener("scroll", activityRegister);`. Please read the doc before asking. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Thank you very much for everything @farvilain :) have a good evening